# phpMyAdmin seems the easiest way to populate my new vBulletin forum with hundreds of new users and articles. How do I do it?

Tags: mysql, excel, database, phpmyadmin, vbulletin

My new vBulletin forum is empty, and I want to encourage new users to visit, like and contribute. But first, I need to make it...not empty. As an admin, I could manually type in a bunch of threads, all from 'admin' - but that won't work. One look at either an empty website or a site filled with admin posts are equally undesirable. So I need to add hundreds of posts from hundreds of users before day one.

I assume that I should do this via the database, which I can access from phpMyAdmin via cPanel. I tried to download (export) the 'user' table with its 74 columns as a CSV table for MS Excel, but when I opened it in Excel, it was not in table form - it was all , and " in a string. If I could only see it laid out nicely in Excel, I could paste hundreds of usernames into the USER table, and and hundreds of articles into the THREAD table. I think. Am I missing something?

I am definitely going to fake it until I make it - there is simply no other way with a new website. The question is whether I have to manually do it from the front end for each user and each new thread (weeks of work), or whether I can paste them all into the database in a couple of hours.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Please provide us information about your actual database and the raw data that you have. I'm not interested about the actual usernames or passwords, so you can provide some ad hoc values for those. I'm interested about the format your raw data has and the table where you want to import it.

Comment: Its the default, empty database for vBulletin version 4.2.5. Raw data? Do you need that? The usernames I will take from a name generator website and the articles I will take from press releases.

Comment: Paul, if you allocate time to address me with a proper question, then I will help you.

Comment: The vBulletin database contains approximately 250 tables. The user and thread tables are two of them. I don't know how they speak to each other throughout the code and which columns and even tables NEED data to avoid coding deficiencies aside from userid, username, email, password in the user table. There are over 100,000 people using vBulletin, and this exact question I have posed must have been answered and executed thousands of times by many, if not most webmasters of vbulletin websites. I don't think I'm breaking new ground by requesting it, but I havent found out how to do it online.

Comment: Paul, you will need to write a MySQL command, possibly generating parts of your query, but I'm confident I can do that for you without much effort. But in order to do so, I need to know how your raw data looks alike, what do you have there. I'm not interested about the actual data, because that's confidential, but if you explain what's there, then I will understand it. I will also need the structure of the user table (run desc user; in MySQL). I will not research the db structure of vBulletin just to answer you. I consider this to be your task and if you provide this information, I'll help.

Comment: I found the table insertion method to be simple for creating users, and informative. For the sake of future visitors, it would be great if you could see my step by step instructions below and translate the table method into the query method. I am guessing that the data I am yet to find for articles will be just as simple to insert into the thread table by merely pasting one article at a time and randomly choosing a userid who submitted it, or something similar. I hope so. Database entry is MUCH faster. I was RIGHT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just regarding Excel, use the 'Text to Columns' tool on the Data tab to convert the CSV string into columns.

Where are you getting the content from to pre-load your forum though? If you have to make it up anyway, then is there much actual time saving in loading data in via phpMyAdmin in reality?

Assuming you have some content available from somewhere though, then you can export to CSV again from Excel and use a CSV to SQL tool (eg. https://codebeautify.org/csv-to-sql-converter though there are others around also) to generate SQL INSERT statements for uploading via phpMyAdmin or other DB tools. (I don't recall if phpMyAdmin has a SQL file upload mechanism or if you just have to paste the SQL into the browser window... have not used it for a good few years now).

Comment: The Text to Columns tool (in Excel, not phpMyAdmin) was hard to use and I received a LOT of error messages without any changes. But I did it: In Excel, I went to Data>Text to Columns and replaced the Comma with Other and inserted a semicolon. The fastest way to do this without too many error messages is to highlight the entire A column in Excel (which could equate to THOUSANDS of columns in the table you are correcting - I know - the ambiguities are endless) before you open the Text to Columns tool in Excel. Then it will warn you that all your data will be replaced. Don't worry - Ambiguity.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it has totally fixed my CSV table in Excel. I just had to explain it for the next person. The CSV to SQL step will follow, so long as there are no values I MUST include specifically in vBulletin so as not to break links etc throughout the forum. There may be other tables that need to be edited other than USER and THREAD. I'll need a vBuletin expert for that.

Comment: I have successfully added 300 new users and avatars on my website! I did this by editing the user.csv file I exported from phpMyAdmin in Excel, then importing it back into the user table.

1. In phpMyAdmin, select the 'user' table in the sidebar. Export>Quick>CSV>Go. It will download as user.csv.

2. Open the user.csv file in Excel, highlight column A and go to Data>Text to Columns>Delimited>Next>Other ;>Next>General>Finish. Click OK or whatever it says on the warning popup.

3. Previous users guide you now. Use the Home>Fill>Down and Home>Fill>Sequence to add as many users as you want.

Comment: 4. Password and Salt can be duplicated from a user above it - its the only thing that works. I recommend abcde12345 or something by registering a previous user. That way you get those two fields for duplication. 5. Add 300 or so names onto the list by simply pasting them into a column. I got mine from a name generator online. 6. Allocate avatar ids based on avatars you put in vbulletin. 7. When you are done with the table, delete row 1 (field names) and all the existing users. Delete those rows. Save your file. (Create backups all the time of course). 8. Import user.csv in the user table.

Comment: 9. That should simply add the new to the existing. Hopefully you checked that nobody registered while you were doing this. You now have a million users or whatever, all with avatars. 10. Go to admincp of vbulletin. Maintenance>Update>Update User names. This will correct the number of members and the latest of your members throughout the site. This method all seems to be working solidly without problems. Adding threads might be similarly easy, but not sure...

Comment: Hey @paul, glad to hear you got sorted there. Reading through your comments there, I was reminded of a tool I use myself on occasion which may be useful to some looking to do similar things - https://randomuser.me/